# Empathy doesn't connect to facebook accout

Tags: 13.04, empathy, facebook, online-accounts

in **System settings >> Online accounts** when i add facebook account it redirects me to the browser and opens a webpage in the photo below and do nothing after that

any help ??[image: Photo]

Comment: Try open the web page in Firefox or change the default web browser to Firefox. TQ.

Comment: i did it on firefox , chrome and chromium

Comment: this happened to me, using firefox and empathy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One line command fix following **sallp** previous answer (copy paste in terminal):

```
sudo sed -i.bak "/<setting name=\"ClientId\">/a\          <setting name=\"AllowedSchemes\" type=\"as\">\['https','http'\]<\/setting>" /usr/share/accounts/providers/facebook.provider
```

If it does not work for you, you can still rollback to the previous version of the file by using the backup with:

```
sudo mv /usr/share/accounts/providers/facebook.provider.bak /usr/share/accounts/providers/facebook.provider
```

Hope it'll help!

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to chime in on the issue in order to add clarity.  I'm reiterating the discussion from this ubuntu forum post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2146595

The problem that everyone is happening is due to the Facebook 'Secure Browsing' option. This requires that Facebook logins and connections use HTTPS, instead of HTTP (secure HTTP vs normal HTTP). By default, I believe online accounts is using HTTP, so this just won't work.

Because of this, we have a couple of options.

**Option 1** (Insecure Solution):
Disable Facebook Secure browsing through the security interface on Facebook.com. This will disable HTTPS defaults on ALL of your Facebook pages on ALL devices, e.g. cell phones, other computers, etc. This works, but it is not the ideal solution.

**Option 2** (Right Way):
We can simply request that online accounts just use an HTTPS connection, instead of an HTTP connection. To do this, we can use Derek Karpinski's previous advice (quoted below). This is essentially telling Online Accounts to try both HTTP and HTTPS. Since Facebook needs HTTPS, this is what we want. After doing his steps below, delete the Ubuntu app on Facebook (if you had previously tried and failed to add it), log out of Facebook, and close Online Accounts. You actually don't need to restart your computer, just close Online Accounts. Re-open Online Accounts and try again. and things should work fine!

This is how you fix it, run this command in a terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/accounts/providers/facebook.provider
```

It will open text editor.  The file in question is the facebook account profile.
Add this line:

```
<setting name="AllowedSchemes" type="as">['https','http']</setting>
```

right after this line:

```
<group name="user_agent">
```

Save the file and close the text editor.  You will now be able to properly enter your facebook credentials from the online accounts panel.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center-signon/+bug/1180297 
 do is
gksu gedit /usr/share/accounts/providers/facebook.provider

add < setting name="AllowedSchemes" type="as">['https','http'] with the others settings remove the space after <
and save
it worked for me but the guy who posted it said that it exposes your desktop to some security risks

Comment: the link is valid

Comment: sallp the link you provided is invalid, you may were trying to link to a comment that were deleted, any way you guys can still use this one https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center-signon/+bug/1180297.